# ElementNotInteractableException pops up when I run a Python Selenium Script on a Google Cloud Virtual Machine but the error does NOT show up locally

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I have a simple Python Selenium script that I use to scrape this [webpage](https://wolt.com/en/discovery/restaurants). It runs perfectly on my local machine, but when I deploy it to a virtual machine on Google Cloud, I get an `ElementNotInteractableException` when I try to click on an element on the webpage. The element refers to the **address icon** on the top left-hand side of the page and this is its **XPATH selector** `//div[@data-projection-id='2']/button`.

Here's a quick GIF showing the expected code behavior
[Wolt GIF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HAY4gn8W0THu6XcUKvCVLDmq9NGKTDMs/view?usp=sharing)

**Here's a trimmed down version of the code. The code fails at the last line**

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
    filename="wolt_scraping_logs.log",
    level="INFO",
    format="%(asctime)s  - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
    encoding="utf-8"
)

# Set the Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized") # Required for a maximized Viewport
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging', 'enable-automation', 'disable-popup-blocking']) # Disable pop-ups to speed up browsing
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True) # Keeps the Chrome window open after all the Selenium commands/operations are performed 
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'}) # Operate Chrome using English as the main language
chrome_options.add_argument('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false') # Disable images
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions') # Disable extensions
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=new") # Operate Selenium in headless mode
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') # Disables the sandbox for all process types that are normally sandboxed. Meant to be used as a browser-level switch for testing purposes only
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu') # An additional Selenium setting for headless to work properly, although for newer Selenium versions, it's not needed anymore
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080") # Set the Chrome window size to 1920 x 1080

# Global inputs
base_url = "https://wolt.com/en/discovery/restaurants"

# Instantiate a webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# Navigate to the target URL
logging.info("Navigate to the target URL...")
driver.get(base_url)

# Maximize the window
logging.info("Maximize the window...")
driver.maximize_window()

# Click on the "Accept Cookies" button
logging.info("Click on the 'Accept Cookies' button")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-localization-key='gdpr-consents.banner.accept-button']")))
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//button[@data-localization-key='gdpr-consents.banner.accept-button']").click()

# Click on the "Delivery to" button
logging.info("Click on the 'Delivery to' button")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-projection-id='2']/button")))
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[@data-projection-id='2']/button").click() # The code fails here
```

**... and this is the error message I get on the virtual machine**

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wolt-crawler/wolt_finland_scraping_script.py", line 73, in <module>
    driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[@data-projection-id='2']/button").click()
  File "/home/omarmoataz6/venv-scraping/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 93, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/home/omarmoataz6/venv-scraping/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 403, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/home/omarmoataz6/venv-scraping/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/omarmoataz6/venv-scraping/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=112.0.5615.49)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x5629637d4603 <unknown>
#1 0x562963525741 <unknown>
#2 0x562963562c43 <unknown>
#3 0x562963557025 <unknown>
#4 0x562963582402 <unknown>
#5 0x562963556891 <unknown>
#6 0x5629635825ce <unknown>
#7 0x56296359a9a9 <unknown>
#8 0x5629635821d3 <unknown>
#9 0x562963554fb8 <unknown>
#10 0x5629635560ee <unknown>
#11 0x56296379b046 <unknown>
#12 0x56296379e3c3 <unknown>
#13 0x56296379ec5a <unknown>
#14 0x5629637a6b0e <unknown>
#15 0x56296379f3ec <unknown>
#16 0x562963775ea8 <unknown>
#17 0x5629637bf318 <unknown>
#18 0x5629637bf4c3 <unknown>
#19 0x5629637cce34 <unknown>
#20 0x7fdad2727609 <unknown>
```

Would anyone know why the code fails on the VM but not locally? I've tried to figure it out on my own but couldn't pinpoint the culprit.

Comment: try scrolling to element before performing a click or set the window size to the one that you tested locally in and works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello @Kranthiveer Dontineni and @Abhay Chaudhary. Thank you, guys, for your answers. The blog was a really good read. I found the solution there. Performing the click with Javascript using this command `document.getElementsByClassName('sc-4ed1b0a0-5 gUqbJK')[0].click()` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This [**blog**](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/how-to-deal-with-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-exception-using-selenium/) written by **Shalini Baskaran** gives a detailed description on what is meant by **ElementNotInteractableException**, what are the factors that cause this exception and how to mitigate them.

**What is meant by ElementNotInteractableException?**

> The exception “ElementNotInteractableException” usually occurs when
> the WebElement we want to interact with (or click) is not clickable at
> that point. This essentially means that the click operation on the
> WebElement would result in an exception.

**What are the factors that cause this exception?**

> 1. WebElement to be clicked is disabled.
> 2. WebElement is not yet available (or loaded) on the web page.
> 3. WebElements overlap with each other.
> 4. Failure in locating WebElement using coordinates on the page.

The problem which you're facing now might be caused by the **`4th  Scenario: Failure in locating WebElement using coordinates on the page`**, as said by **`Abhay Chaudhary`** the resolutions of the browser will differ from your local system to VM as a result the element coordinates will also vary, go through the given blog for more information on how to troubleshoot this issue.